# WINE Doesn't Find the Font from /home/user/.fonts?

Tags: wine, games, fonts

There is this visual novel I keep trying to run. Everything else works but the actual text is shown as `[][][][][]`, which signals that the font is missing.

From the screenshot, I have recognized that the font is *LiberationSans*.
So, I downloaded all the variations of LiberationSans and placed them in `/home/user/.fonts` (which I hear is the location where WINE should be able to fetch them from), but nothing changed...

Comment: Do you mean `/home/user/.fonts/` ?  (ie. ~/.fonts/) and did you run `fc-cache` to re-create your font-cache?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, wine software uses different font resource that may not available in system font or user font. and the game/software that you trying to run may have a different font that wine doesn't have in its resource folder if possible try to change your wine font or

if the game/software that you trying to run have a Microsoft font the consider running

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

or copy the font manually to ~./wine/windows/fonts

Comment: I did have `msttcorefonts` and I moved to that folder, but nothing changed.

Comment: tell me which software you trying to run. you say it's a visual novel. is there any chance that the novel is in Japanese then download Japanese font or go to games settings change language

Comment: @vyshu Lilipalace, no the menu, and submenus are in English, so everything else should be English.

Comment: this game has a Japanese subtitle. check to see if the settings have the right font displayed (Like if you want the English language then change it to English) in side the game

Comment: and also see the subtitle language most visual novel have this option

Comment: @vyshy it's already English (the very first screen says "This game is an English version".

Comment: do you actually know which font that game use? does this  font is your LiberationSans assumption there are different fonts that looks like this

Comment: @vyshu Now that I think of it I'm not sure, I thought one of those recognize font sites, said that it's LiberationSans, but now some say it's Hoxton North. Is there a way to tell which font is missing for sure?

Comment: the best way is to go to your game folder and check by your self. use the search function and find *.ttf now look the names of the font and search it in google and download it. this game is design to run out of the box for windows then there will be a font that default windows may use so copy the windows fonts and paste to the above locations it may work like that try it

Comment: Finding .tff from .exe?

Comment: I mean go to your program files inside your .wine folder and check

Comment: I found nothing...

Comment: find a windows machine if possible check current font's and copy them and install that game in that machine and check your windows font again the extra font that wasn't available before is the font that the game uses if you can't find any windows machine try a virtual machine. or play in that machine instead

Comment: even if I could test it with a window machine, how would I know what font it uses any better than from screenshots?

Comment: mostly they have a name in the ttf file use that name and search it in google

Comment: I know that... But I have no idea about any .ttf because the game is just .exe...

Comment: just exe ?  is the game a runner exe ? not an installer one?

Comment: then try to run in windows if it works fine then copy all font's to the font folder of your .wine folder. you can find windows font's in C:\Windows\Fonts

Comment: runner.exe yes, it has some .dll and .dat files as well, but that's it.

Comment: Run in Windows?

Comment: basically you need to confirm that it is working fine in windows

Comment: it does in windows, according to all other people bought it... Doesn't msttcorefonts already feature windows fonts? It's already installed.

Comment: put this font's to wine folder ~/.wine/windows/fonts

Comment: That was the first thing I tried...

Comment: do you think it's too much to run a game... you want to complete it even after this much of work then I recommend to run it in windows VM. or re-run it in "play on Linux " or proton

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a stupid amount of work, I have already fought with a long time, but keep coming back to it... The first thing I did was try running it with Proton.

Comment: it didn't work?

Comment: I did this thing for some visual novels of mine. and in most cases, it worked for me. there are games that don't work with Linux that much. it may be one of those cases

Comment: If it had worked, I wouldn't try running it with WINE.

Comment: I think you where one of the curiosity types

Comment: Regardless, thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: nice talking to you.bye